# I cant get move_base source files

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried following [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/246775/where-is-the-source-code-of-installed-packages/) answer, but with apt-get source I always get this on any package

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for ros-kinetic-move-base
```

I found source files on [github](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/melodic-devel/move_base) but I want to get them in package folder. How can I get move_base source files so I can edit them, or any files source files?

EDIT:
ok so i get the files with apt-get source, but how do i put them in move_base directory so i can edit them there and it gets saved and compiled??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301627/i-cant-get-move_base-source-files/) by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-26**:
Did you follow the instructions in #q12478 to setup the apt source repositories?

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-08-26**:
yes, still getting the same error
EDIT: ok, i did it, thank you :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-26**:
So what did you do in the end?

If you made a mistake, but then got things to work please post what you did as an answer so others can learn.

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-08-28**:
i followed answers from that question and after sudo apt-get update it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to clone and build the move_base package into your workspace. So:

Go to your workspace `src` space:

```
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src
```

Put/clone here the package from the `kinetic-devel` branch:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/kinetic-devel
```

Once you do this you can compile the workspace. It should compile successful although there might be some dependencies missing that you will need to install.In that case navigate to your workspace:

```
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws
```

and to install missing dependencies run:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -ryi --rosdistro=kinetic
```

Next thing to do is source your setup.bash. Once again navigate to your workspace:

```
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws
```

and run there:

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

and you should be able to use and edit the package.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-08-28**:
ok, i did it but now i get this error when running movebase node without editing anything in the package.

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [move_base/move_base]: can't locate node [move_base] in package [move_base]
```

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-08-29**:
actually, you want only the move_base,  not the whole navigation stack so just clone the [move_base package](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/kinetic-devel/move_base). You should still have the navigation stacked already installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation
```

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-08-29**:
regarding the new error message, maybe [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/207110/there-is-no-move_base-node-in-move_base-package/) question can help.

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-08-29**:
I just reinstalled ROS and git cloned navigation files. Now everything is working